# ADT Eclipse + gradle + dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

Has anyone managed to make adt + gradle work together on his android apps? I wrote my build.gradle file using gradle plugin by spring and it builds just fine. However the adt thinks that there are no local libs attached to the project (appcompat) so it hits error at my resource files.

So my question is how to fully intergrade a gradle build with adt? Or should I ask how to fool eclipse ADT into thinking that all local libs are there without actually adding the lib projects to workspace?

I don't wanna use Intellij or Android Studio. I tried them but they are confusing and complicated to me. I wanna use eclipse for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Eclipse dudes just told me that this will be available soon via a project called Andmore. they will handle and continue the developing of adt now that google has dropped support on it.

This is still a work in progress but they expect to start bootstrapping the project soon.